# Changes value stored in mutable array unexpectedly in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have data from **web service** to be displayed. I am getting the data correctly and it has been displayed in `tableview`. I am storing the `cells` that are being displayed/created in a `mutable array` for the purpose of loading them next time with out the use of web service. First time the data has been stored correctly in array ,but the value stored in the the array changes automatically !!!

I did check the portion of code where I am inserting cells and it works only as per the number of items ie. if I have 5 data from service it stores only 5 values and it works only 5 times. Then how does it changes ??

Answer (score 0):

iOS only creates about as many cells as are displayed at one time and then reuses them once once scrolls of screen. As you scroll through the table, the cells in your array are being reused and the new content from the web service is replacing the content from earlier responses from the web service.

Rather than saving the cell in an array, save the content from the web service in the array or dictionary or other appropriate collection, then update the cells from the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I am trying to load content to tableview only after getting complete data from the web service. Usually I handle this the way that you have specified . But here I am calling web service 2 times in the same class it self and I have image to be loaded. So I have handled the 2 service calls in the view controller class & image url call in tableview cell class.  As a result I wont get the loaded image data to view controller class. Thats why I am storing the entire cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

The data changes automatically because you are storing reusable cells (might be used elsewhere if they are not on screen anymore). Don't store cells, store the data objects and load them from array or dictionary using indexPath passed to the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Please refer my comment to bobnoble's answer. I have explained the scenario more clearly

Comment: I would get images stored in the array also, and just pass them to the cell. Storing cells is definitely not an option.